# awk shell variable with field separator

Tags: bash, awk

I am trying to create a hash:

```
 awk -F ';' '/DHCP/ {for(i=1; i<=5; i++) {getline; print $2$1}}' file \
 | awk '{print $1"=>\"0000:0000:0000:1000::"$2"/64\""}'
```

returns me the following :

```
host1=>"0000:0000:0000:1000::2/64"
host2=>"0000:0000:0000:1000::3/64"
host3=>"0000:0000:0000:1000::4/64"
host4=>"0000:0000:0000:1000::5/64"
host5=>"0000:0000:0000:1000::6/64"
```

This is all fine, but notice the `5` in the for loop in `awk`. How can I retrieve the total number of lines of the `file` into that for loop?

I can use `wc -l` into a variable, but how to use the shell variable and field separator `;` together with awk ?

#### ADD

This is what the `file` looks like :

```
#rest are dynamically assigned by DHCP server
2   ; host1            ; server1 ; ; ;
3   ; host2            ; sX ;;
4   ; host3            ; plic ;; 
5   ; host4        ; cluc ;;
6   ; host6        ; blah ;;
```

Comment: Can you also post the contents of `file` (of course, anonymized if necessary)?

Comment: You want to process everything starting from the line with `DHCP` to the end of the file?

Comment: @Barmar yes. I have added an example file.

Comment: Is the `DHCP` header line always the first line, or can it be anywhere in the file?

Comment: @Barmar `DHCP` is not the first line in the file. But after it is at the begnning of the file.

Comment: Huh? How can the beginning of the file be after the line with DHCP?

Comment: @Barmar I screwed up my comment. DHCP is at the begnning of the file, but the host and IPs are after the this pattern

Comment: So DHCP *is* on the first line. That makes things easier, just check `NR > 1` to know if you're past the heading line.

Comment: The use of consecutive invocations of `awk` is almost always unnecessary.

Comment: ...as is the use of `getline`. If you're ever considering using it, first read http://awk.info/?tip/getline and make sure you fully understand it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk -F'[ \t]*;[ \t]*' 'NR > 1 && NF > 1 { print $2"=>\"0000:0000:0000:1000::"$1"/64\"" }'  file
```

I've gotten rid of the check for `DHCP` -- I just test if we're past the first line. And `NF > 1` makes sure that we don't do anything on a blank line.

I combined the two uses of `awk` into one by using a more elaborate field separator. It matches `;` and any whitespace around it.

Comment: Nice, elegant. I like.

Comment: @Barmar, thanks. It prints the line with `#` as well.

Comment: I've revised, and tested this.

Comment: Yes, it does work except if there is a blank line it adds `=>"0000:0000:0000:1000::/64"`. I have upvoted

Comment: I've added a check that there are at least 2 fields in the row before printing

Comment: perfect. Thanks a lot. Accepted your elegant answer.

Answer (score 0):

`awk -v IT=$(cat file1|wc -l) -F ';' '/DHCP/ {for(i=1; i<=IT; i++) {getline; print $2$1}}' file \| awk '{print $1"=>\"0000:0000:0000:1000::"$2"/64\""}'`

The -v flag passes external variables to awk.

```
@Ed Morton on my system catting executed faster  
(precise)cronkilla@localhost:/tmp$ time wc -l < file1
4

real    0m0.003s
user    0m0.001s
sys     0m0.002s
(precise)cronkilla@localhost:/tmp$ time cat file1 | wc -l
4

real    0m0.003s
user    0m0.001s
sys     0m0.001s
```

Comment: Not quite, if you use cat without piping it it will print the filename.

Comment: It is UUOC. Use `wc -l < file` instead of `cat file | wc -l`. Yjay `getline` statement can cause you all sorts of problems too. Make sure you read and fully understand http://awk.info/?tip/getline before using getline. It's also almost never useful to have 1 awk script piped to another.